# Laravel 5.5 Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my LoginController under Auth, I have used the following codes:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Model\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Hash;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Model\UserAdmin;

class LoginController extends Controller {
use AuthenticatesUsers;
public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

public function doLogin(Request $request) {
$userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'status' => '1',
        );
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($userdata)) {
  return Redirect::intended('/administrator/dashboard')->with('successMessage', 'You have successfully logged in.');
}
}
}
```

And in UserAdmin (model) under app/Model is as follows:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Config;
class UserAdmin extends Authenticatable {
protected $table = 'adminusers';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'company', 'website'];

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // Don't forget this, you'll never know what's being done in the constructor of the parent class you extended
    }

}
```

After submitting the login details, it shows me the error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Model\UserAdmin given, called in /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php on line 379

Comment: Is https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/671 this related?

Comment: @Vishal - I did exactly the same as the link you mentioned above, but nothing happen. I dd('XX'); after Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($userdata) but dd is not working.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I suppose that you required to add implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable to your UserAdmin model class definition.

```
    class UserAdmin extends Model implements 
    \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and will save you a massive headache. Replace `extends model` with the `extends Authenticatable` as shown above.

Comment: Under Laravel 8 this no longer works. Use `class UserAdmin extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` instead.

Answer (score 16):

You must use Authenticatable in User model

for example:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  //your code
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in 2023 (Laravel 10)!!

Answer (score 6):

You must declared use AuthenticableTrait for Authenticatable interface.

For example :

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
use AuthenticableTrait;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must extends Authenticatable class and implements JWTSubject in User model

For example :

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and run 'composer dump-autoload' to check for "ambiguous User class resolution". It is likely you have two classes Defined as  User Class.

Answer (score 1):

> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

Then in your model class, extends `AuthenticatesUsers` instead of `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Model and instead of extending Model, extend User

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Staff extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{
}
```